# How do I remove unwanted Text Frame space in Indesign?

Tags: adobe-indesign, text

I've been struggling with this one for a while. When I create a Text Frame, there seems to be space at the top of the frame that I don't want. Even if I use frame options to centre the text there's still more space at the top.

[image]

Text frame set to normal

[image]

Text frame set to centre.

Why is this? And is it possible to remove?

Comment: I think it has something to do with the way the font was built, not InDesign. Keen to hear if someone has an answer though!

Comment: I have the same problem, and run into it frequently. I have several text boxes with the same font, and same attributes, but arbitrarily the text aligns perfectly with the top inset margin, or doesn't. Text frame settings are exactly the same. Paragraph settings are the same. I can't find any difference. You'll see a color difference in the image, but I have various colors of the text among the page and there's no pattern there. I've run into this with and without an inset margin set on text boxes. Most of these boxes were created by duplicating previous text boxes, if not all of them.

Comment: @user155997, If First Baseline > Offset is set to Cap Height, your problem could be that some of the text in the text frames align to the baseline grid, that some object with Text Wrap is pushing away the text or perhaps that the texts have different Baseline Shift.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is in fact based on the font you're using, and how it's built, as @Alex mentioned above. Here's an example of four different fonts, same font size, exact same setting in each text box:

[image]

The first font is standard Arial. The second it a fairly common sans-serif font, AG Book Pro. The third and fourth are fancier fonts I got from dafont.com. As you can see, the more standard fonts have very little to no spacing around them at all. The other two have random spacing either at the top or bottom.

As a side note, it's also possible to change the spacing around text by using the Text Frame Options dialog (Cmd+B on Mac, Ctrl+B on PC), and editing the "Inset Spacing" numbers. You can do it uniformly by keeping the "link" icon clicked, or unclick it to edit the dimensions individually for top-left-bottom-right.

I don't think this is the cause of OP's issue, however.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### Vertically Center Text/Paragraph in Text Frame - Indesign CC

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> (using your keyboard)
2. Text Frame Options Pane pop-up, under "General" tab, "Vertical Justification" section; just change Align to be **Center**
3. Then under "Baseline Options" tab, "First Baseline" section; just change Offset to be **x Height**
4. Then click OK, and good luck

[image: Vertically Center Text/Paragraph in Text Frame - Indesign CC]

Comment: Can you explain using words? Images are supposed to support a written explanation, not be the answer itself.

Comment: Hello Luciano, I think image is more powerful than words.

Comment: @wearewell You may think so, but that is not how StackExchange works. Images are an excellent way of supporting your explanation, but they should not be the explanation in and of themselves—that is official StackExchange policy. It is impossible to search for the text in an image, and screen readers for visually impaired users also cannot do much with them. That is why answers should be able to stand on their own without pictures, the pictures being an additional plus.

Comment: You may also want to explain why you have chosen the x height as the baseline, rather than the cap height, considering that the text in the screenshot is all uppercase.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I am sorry, I didn't get these points before, I'll do my best to provide all my answers with text steps and images will be just additional.

Answer (score 1):

In regards to wearewell's photos, I thinking selecting "Cap Height" instead of "x Height" in Baseline Options would be what you want instead.